# HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract 'GovernanceContract' not found

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, dapps, dapp-development, hardhat

Currently attempting to deploy my smart contracts. However, when running:

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost
```

I am getting the following error:

```
HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "GovernanceContract" not found.
```

Here is my deploy.js script for the 'GovernanceContract', I will attach the entire deployment script for all of my smart contracts bellow:

```
  // GovernanceContract
  const GovernanceContract = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('GovernanceContract');
  const governancecontract = await GovernanceContract.deploy(governancetoken.address, timelock.address, 4, 5, 1);

  await governancecontract.deployed();

  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + `/governancecontract-address.json`,
    JSON.stringify({ address: governancecontract.address }, undefined, 2)
  );

  const GovernanceContractArtifact = artifacts.readArtifactSync("GovernanceContract");

  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + `/governancecontract.json`,
    JSON.stringify(GovernanceContractArtifact, null, 2)
  );

  console.log('GovernanceContract deployed to:', governancecontract.address);
```

Full deployment script:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const hre = require('hardhat');

async function main() {
  // GovernanceToken
  const GovernanceToken = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('GovernanceToken');
  const governancetoken = await GovernanceToken.deploy();

  await governancetoken.deployed();

  const contractsDir = __dirname + "/../pages/contractsData";
  if (!fs.existsSync(contractsDir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(contractsDir);
  }

  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + `/governancetoken-address.json`,
    JSON.stringify({ address: governancetoken.address }, undefined, 2)
  );

  const GovernanceTokenContractArtifact = artifacts.readArtifactSync("GovernanceToken");

  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + `/governancetoken.json`,
    JSON.stringify(GovernanceTokenContractArtifact, null, 2)
  );

  console.log('GovernanceToken deployed to:', governancetoken.address);


  // TimeLock
  const TimeLock = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('TimeLock');
  const timelock = await TimeLock.deploy(3600, [], []);

  await governancetoken.deployed();

  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + `/timelock-address.json`,
    JSON.stringify({ address: timelock.address }, undefined, 2)
  );

  const TimeLockContractArtifact = artifacts.readArtifactSync("TimeLock");

  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + `/timelock.json`,
    JSON.stringify(TimeLockContractArtifact, null, 2)
  );

  console.log('TimeLock deployed to:', timelock.address);


  // GovernanceContract
  const GovernanceContract = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('GovernanceContract');
  const governancecontract = await GovernanceContract.deploy(governancetoken.address, timelock.address, 4, 5, 1);

  await governancecontract.deployed();

  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + `/governancecontract-address.json`,
    JSON.stringify({ address: governancecontract.address }, undefined, 2)
  );

  const GovernanceContractArtifact = artifacts.readArtifactSync("GovernanceContract");

  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + `/governancecontract.json`,
    JSON.stringify(GovernanceContractArtifact, null, 2)
  );

  console.log('GovernanceContract deployed to:', governancecontract.address);


  // Box
  const Box = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('Box');
  const box = await Box.deploy();

  await box.deployed();

  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + `/box-address.json`,
    JSON.stringify({ address: box.address }, undefined, 2)
  );

  const BoxContractArtifact = artifacts.readArtifactSync("Box");

  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + `/box.json`,
    JSON.stringify(BoxContractArtifact, null, 2)
  );

  console.log('Box deployed to:', box.address);

}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: Have you compiled your contract using `npx hardhat compile` ?

Comment: check the spelling of the filename and the same in the deploy script match exactly. 
also try
`npx hardhat clean ; npx hardhat compile`